# Strange HTML5 Canvas drawImage behaviour

Tags: html, html5-canvas, scaling, drawimage

I am writing some code that uses HTML5 canvas. Generally it works well, but now I found a very strange behaviour. The weird thing is that it is consistent on different browsers, so must be that I understood the thing wrong... Despite the docs seem to say exactly what I am doing. Here is the code (it's an object method):

```
   MyCanvas.prototype.getElement = function() {

        var innerHtml = "<div></div>";

        var elem = jQuery(innerHtml, {
            'id' : this.viewId
        });



        var canvas = jQuery("<canvas/>", {
            'id' : this.viewId + "canvas",
            'width' : this.width,
            'height' : this.height
        });

        var w = this.width;
        var h = this.height;

        jQuery(elem).append(canvas);

        var imgElem = new Image();

        imgElem.src = this.maskImage;
        imgElem.onload = function() {
            var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, w, h);

        };

        return elem;
    };
```

After this I'll use jQuery again to append this element to a Div that is already in the page (which is blank). 
The result will be that the image is overstretched like ten times it's width.... That is weird because, for what I understood of drawImage, it should use the w and h values to scale the image and given that w and h are the size of the canvas, it should fit well.

What am I doing wrong? Is it because I do the drawing off the rendered DOM tree?

Comment: Could you post all the javascript and html?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found this "feature" as well to be a bit irksome.  It seems as though you don't want to use CSS to set the width and height properties for the canvas element.  Append the canvas element with attributes (rather than CSS) and the dimensions should correct themselves.

```
var canvas = jQuery("<canvas/>", {
    'id' : this.viewId + "canvas"
});

$('#' + this.viewId).attr('height', this.height).attr('width', this.width);
```

Comment: It's actually really important that a canvas have a width and height defined by element attributes.  Those dimensions determine how many pixels are in the canvas' raster surface; the CSS width and height describe how large the canvas will be in the page.

Comment: This had me quite stumped, because nothing I was doing was coming out correctly, even though the canvas was sized right in the browser.  Thanks!