# Resizing a .png image when drawing to HTML5 canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a few .png images to the HTML5 canvas using JavaScript. I currently have a function that will draw an image to the canvas, but the image is too large for the canvas, so only part of it displays.

The function I currently have is:

```
function drawImage(x, y){
            var numberImage = new Image();
            numberImage.src = imageSource;
            context.drawImage(numberImage, x, y);

        }
```

and I call the function by using:

```
var image1 = new Image();

image1.onLoad = function(){
                context.drawImage(image1, 50, 50);
                };
            image1.src="1.png";
```

I was just wondering if anyone knows of a way of resizing an image when it's drawn to the canvas, so that I could just a thumbnail sized image?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried adding parameters in to the drawImage function to resize the image, but this doesn't seem to have made any difference...

```
var image1 = new Image();

image1.onLoad = function(){
                context.drawImage(image1, 50, 50, 10, 10);
                };
            image1.src="1.png";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble finding the problem in your code... But I found it !

You gonna hate this : you wrote image.onLoad instead of image.onload... yes, **javascript is case-sensitive**. :-)

correct code is :

```
var image1 = new Image();

image1.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(image1, 50, 50, 10, 10);
                };
            image1.src="1.png";
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you using CSS to set the size of the canvas? You need to set a height and width on the element instead or everything in your canvas will be scaled "unexpectedly". This could be your problem.

See [Strange HTML5 Canvas drawImage behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185631/strange-html5-canvas-drawimage-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

drawImage() takes additional width and height parameter:

```
   context.drawImage(image, x, y, width, heighT)
```

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!mdn+drawimage

Comment: Yeah, there's two "overloaded" versions of the method.

Comment: I've tried adding in parameters for width and height, but when I refresh the page in the browser, the image is still far too large...

Comment: image1.onLoad = function(){
     context.drawImage(image1, 50, 50, 10, 10);
     };
    image1.src="1.png";

Comment: Original post edited, to show the added width and height parameters.

Comment: please post a jsfiddle of your code. The code submitted by Mikko works fine