# How can you resize a new image object without cropping it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, object

Is there a way to load an image larger or smaller without cropping? I don't want it to look smaller or larger.  I want it to actually be smaller or larger.  I tried using [these parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd757809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a new Image() object, are there any more?

```
_img = new Image(50, 50); //These parameters will crop it
_img.addEventListener('load',onImage,false);
_img.width = 50;//This will crop it.  

_img.style.width = "50px";//This doesn't change the original width to read `50`.  
console.log(_img.width);
```

Comment: go to this answer : possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747101/resize-crop-pad-a-picture-to-a-fixed-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your question is unclear, I think you have to use canvas to redraw it after on load...this answer might give you a direction 
[Resizing a .png image when drawing to HTML5 canvas using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311311/resizing-a-png-image-when-drawing-to-html5-canvas-using-javascript)