# What does getBoundingClientRect() mean?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some inconsistencies when trying to draw some lines between elements that I find on the DOM using CSS selectors, and believe it may be to do with the method I am calling getBoundingClientRect().

If anybody could provide any information about how the top, left, bottom, right are calculated for a boundingClientRect, specifically with respect to HTML canvases I would really appreciate it.

An example of an inconsistency I am getting is that when I do canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top I get 70. Then I have an element in the DOM which I find and calculates its top, which is 334. When I subtract the two to find the offset (334 - 70 = 264), however when I draw a grid on the canvas I can clearly see that the element is greater than 275, almost 280.

I think the real question is, does this method always give a top and a bottom with respective to the same rect, as this is the only explanation I can come up with for the inconsistencies.

Thanks

Comment: [The MDN#Value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#Value) May be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The `getBoundingClientRect` returns coordinates relative to the viewport. It means that it doesn't take window (body) scroll position into account.

> Properties other than width and height are relative to the top-left of the viewport.

For example, if the window is scrolled down by 10px, you have to add 10 to the returned `top` value to get the element top-left corner coordinates relative to the document top-left corner.

Maybe your window was scrolled and that messed up your calculations.

If you use `jQuery`, you can use its `offset` method, which returns coordinates relative to the document top-left corner, and by the way, uses `getBoundingClientRect` internally (at least newer versions).

Comment: This was a good point, but didn't solve the problem, the solution was to do with scaling and I urge people using HTML canvas to be very careful about making sure they set the canvas attributes as shown in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185631/strange-html5-canvas-drawimage-behaviour

Comment: Ok I'm glad you found the solution.